# Disjoint Object Properties vs Disjoint Classes

Tags: semantic-web, owl, ontology

If you look at the [OWL 2 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/), the following axioms have been defined:

**Disjoint Properties**

> DisjointObjectProperties( a:hasFather a:hasMother ) Fatherhood is disjoint with motherhood.
>   ObjectPropertyAssertion( a:hasFather a:Stewie a:Peter ) Peter is Stewie's father.
>   ObjectPropertyAssertion( a:hasMother a:Stewie a:Lois )  Lois is the mother of Stewie.

**Disjoint Classes**

> DisjointClasses( a:Boy a:Girl ) Nothing can be both a boy and a girl.
>   ClassAssertion( a:Boy a:Stewie )    Stewie is a boy.

So my question is that if I want define the following:

```
Declaration( NamedIndividual( a:Peter ) )
Declaration( NamedIndividual( a:Lois ) )
ClassAssertion( a:Father a:Peter )
ClassAssertion( a:Mother a:Lois )
```

and then to define disjointness, do I need (1) or (2) or both at the same time:

```
(1) DisjointObjectProperties( a:hasFather a:hasMother )
(2) DisjointClasses( a:Mother a:Father )
```

to be able to make the reasoner aware that **No mother can be father**? Isn't it the case that defining both would just be redundant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention any connection between the classes Mother and Father and the properties hasMother and hasFather, so it's hard to tell whether you're making some additional assumptions (e.g., that the range of hasMother is Mother).

When you assert that classes C and D are disjoint, you're saying that for every individual x, it cannot be the case that C(x) and D(x)

When you assert that properties P and Q are disjoint, you're saying that for every pair of individuals x and y, it cannot be the case that both P(x,y) and Q(x,y).

Now, suppose you have an ontology with classes Mother and Father, and properties hasMother and hasFather, **which have as ranges** Mother and Father.  That means that whenever you have hasMother(a,m) you can infer that Mother(m), and whenever you have hasFather(a,f), you can infer that Father(f).

In this particular case, if you declare Mother and Father disjoint, this has the side effect of making hasMother and hasFather disjoint, because if you had hasMother(x,y) and hasFather(x,y), then you would have that Mother(y) and Father(y), which is inconsistent.

In this particular case, if you declare that hasMother and hasFather are disjoint, you *do not* have the side effect of making Mother and Father disjoint classes.  You could, for instance, have hasMother(x1,y) and hasFather(x2,y), and from that infer that Mother(y) and Father(y).

Comment: So does this mean that if I don't have domain and range for mother and father, then I need both classes and the properties to be disjoint?

Comment: @Artemis That entirely depends on what you want to be able to infer, and you haven't told us that.  You don't **have** to assert anything, after all.

Comment: The only thing I want to infer is that no Mother ever be a Father. My question is if dijointness between classes and properties have the same output, then I can assert only one. I mentioned this in my question. I wanted to make sure, I am not making any modelling mistakes.

Comment: If you want that no Mothers are ever Father, then you should assert that Mother and Father are disjoint classes, period.  If you *don't* do that, but assert that hasMother and hasFather are disjoint properties, you could still have some individual be both a mother and father, just not of the same individual.  E.g., you could have hasMother(x,z) and hasFather(y,z);  i.e., z is the mother of x and the father of y.  You need that the *classes* Mother and Father are disjoint in order to prevent that.